# C - scanf() takes two inputs instead of one

Tags: c

I'm coding a program that simulate dice rolling and I'm stuck with this piece of code:

```
short diceNumber(){
unsigned short dice;
do {
    printf("\nInput the number of dice to roll: ");
    if(!scanf("%hu", &dice)) {
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        scanf("%*c");
        puts("");
        puts("WRONG INPUT!");
    }
    else if(dice <= 0) puts("YOU MUST USE A DICE AT LEAST!");
}while(!scanf("%hu", &dice)|| dice <= 0);

return dice; 
}
```

The problem is that the "scanf" inside the if statement takes two input instead of one, for example:

```
Input the number of dice to roll: 2
```

Then it wants the 2 (or another number) again. The first input isn't scanned. But previously, in another function, the "same" statement is working. Here is the code:

```
void menu () {

unsigned short myAnswer;

puts("Choose the dice type");
puts("");
// A printf statement with all the options
puts("");

do {

    // INPUT VALIDATION SECTION

    printf("\nYour input: ");
    if (!scanf("%hu", &myAnswer)) {
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        scanf("%*c");
        puts("");
    }
// switch statement
} while (myAnswer < 1 || myAnswer > 17);
}
```

I've tried different solutions (like fputs, fflush(stdin), fflush(stdout)) but no one worked. Can you please help me?

Comment: What you're doing with three `scanf` calls, I *guess* that is to handle invalid input and skipping the remainder of the line? Then why don't you simply *read* the whole line, into a buffer, and then use `sscanf` on that buffer?

Comment: As for your problem, how many `scanf("%hu", &dice)` calls do you make? There's a *very big* difference between the non-working and the working loops (hint: take a closer look at their conditions).

Comment: Aside: `!scanf("%hu", &dice)` should be `scanf("%hu", &dice) != 1` or you won't pick up `EOF` returned. Also `dice` can't be `< 0`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I use three scanf calls to handle invalid input. I can try with sscanf.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, <= 0 is useless. By the way with scanf("%hu", &dice) != 1 it wants three input. Maybe should I pair the condition with the sscanf?  EDIT: sorry I didn't noticed another scanf() for a test purpose

Comment: Each additional call to `scanf("%hu", &dice)` you have or add will lead to additional input being needed.

Comment: Well I've removed the scanf from the do...while look and now it works as intended, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the "scanf" inside the if statement takes two input instead of one

No.  The upper code has a set of 3 `scanf()` and another 4th `scanf()`.  It is the 4th one that causes the "takes two input instead of one".

The 3 `scanf()` idea has merit, even if it is unusual, to  read a `unsigned short`.

To fix code and still employ the idea:

```
int diceNumber(void) {
  unsigned short dice;
  for (;;) {
    printf("\nInput the number of dice to roll: ");
    fflush(stdout); // insure output is seen 
    int count = scanf("%hu", &dice);
    if (count == 1) {
      if (dice <= 0) puts("YOU MUST USE A DICE AT LEAST!");
      else break;
    } else if (count == EOF) {  // This case omitted in original code.
      return EOF;  
    }
    scanf("%*[^\n]");  // consume almost all of rest of line
    scanf("%*c");      // consume rest of line (expected \n)
    puts("");
    puts("WRONG INPUT!");
    // if(dice <= 0) not possible for unsigned short
  }
  return (int) dice;  
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem on my code by removing the scanf from the do...while loop. By the way I think i'll implement this version. Next time I'll try to remember to play with return values!

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a scanf in the while statement. That forces the user to enter a new number.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I'm not in front of my laptop since two hours but I was looking at the code from my phone and thanks to @Someprogrammerdude suggestion I've found where the problem is. Thank you by the way!